# can't return json pagination in flask for REST API

Tags: python, json, rest, flask, pagination

I'm working with Miguel Grinberg's Flask REST API repo, and I'm failing to return JSON paginated results. The examples online use html templates, but I just want to return a number of results (20), and eventually return links for the previous and next pages. When I return the code immediately following this sentence, I get "pagination object is not iterable":

```
def get_customers():
    return jsonify({'customers': [customer.get_url() for customer in
                                  Customer.query.paginate(page=1, per_page=1)]})
```

I understand I'm passing the wrong object, but I'm not sure if I should use another module, or if I'm on the right path. Does anyone have a suggestion to reach my end goal?

The original code in Miguel's repo is:

```
@app.route('/customers/', methods=['GET'])
def get_customers():
    return jsonify({'customers': [customer.get_url() for customer in
                                  Customer.query.all()]})
```

The whole file is here: https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/oreilly-flask-apis-video/blob/a460ad9df2e58c13b90f183e81b4e8953eb186cb/orders/api.py

The relevant code I'm working with:

```
class Customer(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'customers'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True)

    def get_url(self):
        return url_for('get_customer', id=self.id, _external=True)

    def export_data(self):
        return {
            'self_url': self.get_url(),
            'name': self.name
        }

    def import_data(self, data):
        try:
            self.name = data['name']
        except KeyError as e:
            raise ValidationError('Invalid customer: missing ' + e.args[0])
        return self


@app.route('/customers/', methods=['GET'])
def get_customers():
    return jsonify({'customers': [customer.get_url() for customer in
                                  Customer.query.paginate(page=1, per_page=1)]})

@app.route('/customers/<int:id>', methods=['GET'])
def get_customer(id):
    return jsonify(Customer.query.get_or_404(id).export_data())
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See [the API docs](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.3/api/#flask_sqlalchemy.Pagination).

If you want to iterate over a Pagination object, use (for example)

```
 Customer.query.paginate(page=1, per_page=1).items
```

which is a collection of the items for that page.

Comment: As in, you want to have a JSON representation of the pagination object?

I suspect you'll have to do that "manually". Write a function that you pass the pagination object to that will produce the JSON you desire. Or implement a superclass of Pagination that has that behaviour.